# Python Joblib Parallel: How to combine results per worker?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ram, joblib

**Context**

I have a function that produces a large 2D `numpy` array (with fixed shape) as output. I am calling this function 1000 times using `joblib` (`Parallel` with a `multiprocessing` backend) on 8 CPUs. At the end of the job, I add up all the arrays element-wise (using `np.sum`) to produce a single 2D array that I am interested in. However, when I attempt this, I run out of RAM. I assume that this is because the 1000 arrays would need to be stored in RAM until they are summed at the end.

**Question**

Is there a way to get each worker to add up its arrays as it goes? For example, worker 1 would add array 2 to array 1, and then discard array 2 before computing array 3, and so on. This way, there would only be a maximum of 8 arrays (for 8 CPUs) stored in RAM at any point in time, and these could be summed up at the end to get the same answer.

Comment: Do the arguments stay the same for the 1000 calls?

Comment: @Darkonaut  Same arguments, but different values are passed to the arguments on each call. My quick fix for now is to do 10 sequential runs, each with 100 parallel function calls... but there must be a better way!

Comment: Are the arguments for the 1000 calls known before you start the whole thing or are they calculated on the fly?
How much can the time it takes to calculate one array, vary with the actual argument?
Btw it's always called "arguments" when you talk about values, else it's called "parameters".

Comment: The arguments are known in advance and the time does not vary much with the different arguments. (Thanks for clarifying the terminology!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The facts that you know your arguments in advance and the time for calculation not varying much with the actual argument(s) simplifies the task. It allows for assigning complete jobs for every worker process at start and just summing up the results at the end, just how you proposed.

In the code below every spawned process gets an "equal" (as much as possible) part of all arguments (its `args_batch`) and sums up the intermediate results from calling the target function in it's own result-array. These arrays get summed up finally by the parent process.

The "delayed" function here in the example is not the target function which calculates an array, but a processing function (`worker`) to which the target function (`calc_array`) gets passed as part of the `job` along with the batch of arguments.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import repeat
from time import sleep
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def calc_array(v):
    """Create an array with specified shape and
    fill it up with value v, then kill some time.

    Dummy target function.
    """
    new_array = np.full(shape=SHAPE, fill_value=v)
    # delay result:
    cnt = 10_000_000
    for _ in range(cnt):
        cnt -= 1

    return new_array


def worker(func, args_batch):
    """Call func with every packet of arguments received and update
    result array on the run.

    Worker function which runs the job in each spawned process.
    """
    results = np.zeros(SHAPE)
    for args_ in args_batch:
        new_array = func(*args_)
        np.sum([results, new_array], axis=0, out=results)

    return results


def main(func, arguments, n_jobs, verbose):

    with Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose) as parallel:

        # bundle up jobs:
        funcs = repeat(func, n_jobs)  # functools.partial seems not pickle-able
        args_batches = np.array_split(arguments, n_jobs, axis=0)
        jobs = zip(funcs, args_batches)

        result = sum(parallel(delayed(worker)(*job) for job in jobs))
        assert np.all(result == sum(range(CALLS_TOTAL)))

    sleep(1)  # just to keep stdout ordered
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    SHAPE = (4, 4)  # shape of array calculated by calc_array
    N_JOBS = 8
    CALLS_TOTAL = 100
    VERBOSE = 10
    ARGUMENTS = np.asarray([*zip(range(CALLS_TOTAL))])
    # array([[0], [1], [2], ...]])
    # zip to bundle arguments in a container so we have less code to
    # adapt when feeding a function with multiple parameters

    main(func=calc_array, arguments=ARGUMENTS, n_jobs=N_JOBS, verbose=VERBOSE)
```